# How to calculate percentage of total in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

Given a table with columns such as:

```
Date, Type
```

I'm running the following SQL:

```
SELECT Type, count(*) as CountPerType
FROM myTable
WHERE Date between 20200101 and 20200131
GROUP BY count(*)
```

I want to have an extra column `Percentage` which will have `100.0 * CountPerType / SUM(CountPerType)`. What's the most efficient way to do it in PrestoDB (which powers Amazon Athena)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functionality to achieve that. You should always do a group by of non-aggregated fields.

```
select
    Type,
    CountPerType,
    100.0 * CountPerType/sum(CountPerType) over () as columnName
from
(
    SELECT 
        Type, 
        count(*) as CountPerType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Date between 20200101 and 20200131
    GROUP BY 
        Type
) subq
```

Comment: I think in your window function you need the sum on the whole table, not by type. This one will return 100 for all.

Answer (score 10):

I would write the query without a subquery.  You can mix window functions and aggregation functions:

```
SELECT Type,  COUNT(*) as CountPerType,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as percentage
FROM t
WHERE Date BETWEEN 20200101 AND 20200131
GROUP BY Type;
```

I don't know if the performance is different from the version using the subquery (this should be at least as good).  But the query is definitely simpler.

Comment: the query works fine on the smaller dataset, but the result is wrong by some margin on the bigger dataset. To give more context, it is off by ~1 % on the major contributing rows. The individual count is coming correct, but the percentage number is wrong. Any thoughts on why this might be happening. My column value contains null. Is that causing a problem? I have tried casting one of the numbers in the division to `double`, but that did not help as well.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary . . . This should be *exactly* the calculation that you specify.  I don't know why you think it is wrong.  A subquery should not be changing the results.

Comment: I totally agree with you in theory, but the result that I am getting is not the same as stated in concept .`why you think it is wrong` -> Because I am comparing the result of my query to the manual percentage calculated in excel, and they both differ by ~1-2 % as I said. The individual count in both the places(Excel versus the Athena query result) is same, However, when the percentage is evaluated it is coming as different. For example: Let's say my total count(denominator) is 1000, and my one row count is 50, then expected percentage is 5 %, however, I am getting numbers between ~ 4.5% to 6%.